# Find a sequence of continuously differentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Hello can you help me with this question?

> Given an example of a sequence of continuity differentiable functions $\{f_n\}$ on $[0,1]$ so that $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly but $f$ is not differentiable at all points of $[0,1]$. $Hint$: draw graphs first.

I thought a good answer would be $f(x)$ = $|x|$ where $f_n(x)$= $x(1+1$/$n)$ but I wanted to take your opinion as well

Thanks

Comment: No, it doesn't work.  $|x| = x$ on $[0,1]$, so that $f$ is still differentiable.

Comment: Please retype the question in the image for the convenience!

Comment: Your general idea of trying to make a $V$-shaped limit is a good one though.

Comment: $f$ needs to be not differentiable at **all** points.

Comment: the Weierstrass function?

Comment: what about f(x) = sin(1/x). But what would be the fn then?